# Function which has return type , without a return statement is compiling . Why?

Tags: java

```
public String fun() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
    }
```

Why does the above function compiles without return statement ?

Comment: The compiler is clever enough to know that there is no reachable path which requires a return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does the above function compiles without return statement ?

Because the end of the method is *unreachable* - it will always, always throw a `NullPointerException`.

You should think of the rule as "if the method has a non-void return type, every code path that *returns normally* (doesn't throw an exception) must return a value". In this case, there's no such code path.

This is specified in [JLS 8.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7):

> If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

Comment: Hi Jon , if i replace the " throw new NullPointerException() " with "System.exit(0)" , then it doesn't compile , even though System.exit(0) terminates the program . Why ?

Comment: @syedsaud: Because the compiler doesn't know that `System.exit(0)` cannot complete normally (i.e. without an exception or terminating the VM)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a world in which that was not the behaviour.

```
public static String foo()
{
    if (isValid())
    {
        return "valid";
    }
    throw new InvalidException();

    // Compiler complains "you haven't returned something"
    // even though its not possible to get here
}
```

I'd have to change my code to something like this

```
     //...
     return "this will never happen";
}
```

The compiler is clever enough to know that there is no reachable path which requires a return.

Answer (score 0):

A code path either needs to return a value, or throw an exception.  There is only one code path here, and its to throw the `NullPointerException()`.  `Finally` simply runs code before throwing the exception.